# Change value in react js on window resize

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, responsive-design, lifecycle

I'm building a photo gallery in react js. Obviously it's going to have to be responsive and I've tackled this by setting values like so in the component's render method:

```
let thumbWidth = window.innerWidth >= 480 ? 75 : 100;
```

The problem is that I need the const value to change when the window is resized. My my first attempts was to build a function like so and bind it in the constructor:

```
getThumbWidth = (vpWidth) => {
    if(vpWidth >= 480 ) {
        this.setState({thumbSize: 120}); 
     } else {
        this.setState({thumbSize: 50}); 
     }
}
```

This worked in terms of setting the variable's initial value but how do I trigger the function when the window resizes?

Have tried adding a resize function:

```
resize = () => this.getThumbWidth()
```

...and then changing getThumbWidth so that it sets the value in the component's sate - the idea being that when state is updated the component automatically rerenders:

```
getThumbWidth = (vpWidth) => {
    if(vpWidth >= 480 ) {
        this.setState({thumbSize: 120}); 
     } else {
        this.setState({thumbSize: 50}); 
     }
}
```

And then calling it via lifecycle methods as suggested in several other solutions but the event listener does not appear to be firing:

```
componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.resize)
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.resize)
}
```

Still not working though... any ideas?

Comment: This alone won't solve the question, but, if you want to change value of a variable, why is it defined as a `const`ant in the first place? Hint is in the name, `const` is constant - in other words, constant things do not change, they stay the same. Why not use `let` instead - acts as a same block-scoped variable like `const` does, only the values can change.

Comment: better change const to another type

Comment: Thanks - I spotted that and have changed it - will edit question to reflect this.

Comment: In `getThumbWidth` there's a parameter but when you call it you don't pass this parameter `resize = () => this.getThumbWidth()`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

@Jousi, try this below code works fine of window resize

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      windowSize: "",
      thumbWidth: 75
    };
  }

  handleResize = e => {
    const windowSize = window.innerWidth;
    const thumbWidth = (windowSize >= 480 && 100) || 75;
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return {
        windowSize,
        thumbWidth
      };
    });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.handleResize);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("resize", this.handleResize);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>window size: {this.state.windowSize}</h2>
        <h3>thumbnail width: {this.state.thumbWidth}</h3>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: There is mistake in this answer: should use proper `componentWillUnmount`, instead of `componentWillMount`, when removing event listener.

Answer (score 1):

U can add ref attribute to container of your component:

```
return (
    <div
       className={mainClass}
       ref={(elem) => { this.elem = elem; }}
    >
        your gallery here
   </div>
```

Then in your `componentDidMount` u have access to all events connected to your container. Then u can invoke your function depending on changes on these events. For example:

```
componentDidMount() {
   const parent = this.elem.parentNode;
       if (parent.scrollHeight > parent.clientHeight) {
         parent.onscroll = (() => this.yourMethod(parent));
       } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to initialise the `this.resize` function.

like so: `window.removeEventListener('resize', this.resize())`

Comment: This is incorrect, you shouldn't be invoking this.resize, you should just be passing the reference itself.